# SQL Server uses wrong data types with DBI::dbSendStatement() and DBI::dbBind()

Tags: sql-server, r-dbi

We have a table `[adj].[Assortment Snapshot]` in our SQL Server database with the follwing data types:

```sql
[Customer UUID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[Branch Number] [int] NOT NULL,
[Article Number] [int] NOT NULL,
[Valid On] [date] NOT NULL,
[Comment] [nvarchar](max) NULL
```

I send a query to this table with `dbSendStatement()`...

```sql
<OdbcResult>
  SQL  SELECT [Customer UUID] AS [Customer],
[Branch Number] AS [Branch],
[Valid On] AS [Date],
[Article Number] AS [Article] FROM adj.[Assortment Snapshot] WHERE [Customer UUID] = ? AND [Branch Number] IN (?) AND [Valid On] >= ? AND [Valid On] <= ?
  ROWS Fetched: 0 [complete]
       Changed: 0
```

...followed by `dbBind()` to bind the following parameters:

```r
> print(lstParams)
$param_1_crit_1
[1] "10fb9494-8bc0-11eb-8dcd-0242ac130003"

$param_2_crit_2
[1] 100

$param_3_crit_3
[1] "2021-03-24"

$param_4_crit_4
[1] "2021-04-06"
```

The parameters are of the following classes:

```r
> sapply(lstParams, class)
param_1_crit_1 param_2_crit_2 param_3_crit_3 param_4_crit_4 
   "character"      "integer"         "Date"         "Date"
```

Checking the server logs, this is the query that I get:

```sql
declare @p1 int
set @p1=12
exec sp_prepexec @p1 output,

N'@P1 uniqueidentifier,@P2 int,@P3 nvarchar(10),@P4 nvarchar(10)',

N'SELECT [Customer UUID] AS [Customer],
[Branch Number] AS [Branch],
[Valid On] AS [Date],
[Article Number] AS [Article] 

FROM adj.[Assortment Snapshot] WHERE [Customer UUID] = @P1 AND [Branch Number] IN (@P2) AND [Valid On] >= @P3 AND [Valid On] <= @P4','ED5FADA7-90E9-409F-B210-85E61528E120',3038,N'2021-03-24',N'2021-04-06'
select @p1
```

While the parameter `[Customer UUID]` is correctly recognized as `uniqueidentifier` despite having been passed as `character` by `dbBind()`, the dates are turned into `nvarchar(10)`. Queries involving table-valued SQL functions even result in all parameters being turned into `varchar(255)`.

These conversions mean a huge performance problem: Executing the above SQL query in SQL Server Management Studio returns results almost immediately. The same query executed via `dbSendStatement()` and `dbBind()` takes several seconds to minutes.

How can the conversions described above be avoided?

---

- SQL Server version: 15.00.4102
- R version: Microsoft R Open 4.0.2
- DBI package version: 1.1.1

Comment: Have you read through [Implicit data type conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/machine-learning/r/r-libraries-and-data-types#implicit-data-type-conversions)? Perhaps you could try `lstParams <- list(param_1_crit_1 = "10fb9494-8bc0-11eb-8dcd-0242ac130003", param_1_crit_2 = as.integer(100), param_1_crit_3 = as.POSIXct("2021-03-24"), param_1_crit_4 = as.POSIXct("2021-04-06") )`?

Comment: Thanks @AlwaysLearning for your quick reply. If I am not mistaken, the documentation you linked to describes the conversion of data retrieved from SQL and imported into R. The problem at hand takes place *before* that point: a query performed by SQL Server with the wrong data types.

NB: Using `as.POSIXct()` to convert the dates results in an error `[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Numeric values out of range`.